# Math behind Diffusion models explanation?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, diffusion-models

I am recently reading this wonderful article https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/#what-are-diffusion-models about the math behind the diffusion models ,

As i dont have a math background , i am stuck or not able to understand the below statement,

[image]

I am able to get how the bayes rule is working, **I dont understading what is the reason behind the exponential math below it.**

Kindly explain why it is used and what is the reason behind it or suggest any resources for getting an intuition.

Answer (score 1):

That exponential comes from the PDF of the assumed distribution that you might have missed in the blogpost:

[image]

and

[image]

plug those PDF in that bayes formula and you will end up with those equations

Comment: Can you explain why we need to use exponential and what is the reason behiind it ? I

Comment: @mat it's literally the gaussian PDF, it's not a "reason", it's its definition